# Spark Dataframe stat throwing Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

## What am I trying to do? (Context)

I'm trying to calculate some stats for a dataframe/set in spark that is read from a directory with `.parquet` files about US flights between 2013 and 2015. To be more specific, I'm using `approxQuantile` method in `DataFrameStatFunction` that can be accessed calling `stat` method on a `Dataset`. [See docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameStatFunctions.html)

```
import airportCaseStudy.model.Flight
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object CaseStudy {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    val flights = spark
      .read
      .parquet("C:\\Users\\Bluetab\\IdeaProjects\\GraphFramesSparkPlayground\\src\\resources\\flights")
      .as[Flight]

    flights.show()
    flights.printSchema()
    flights.describe("year", "flightEpochSeconds").show()

    val approxQuantiles = flights.stat
      .approxQuantile(Array("year", "flightEpochSeconds"), Array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 0.25)
    // whatever...
  }
}
```

`Flight` is simply a case class.

```
package airportCaseStudy.model

case class Flight(year: Int, quarter: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int, dayOfWeek: Int, flightDate: String,
                  uniqueCarrier: String, airlineID: String, carrier: String, tailNum: String, flightNum: Int,
                  originAirportID: String, origin: String, originCityName: String, dstAirportID: String,
                  dst: String, dstCityName: String, taxiOut: Float, taxiIn: Float, cancelled: Boolean,
                  diverted: Float, actualETMinutes: Float, airTimeMinutes: Float, distanceMiles: Float, flightEpochSeconds: Long)
```

## What's the issue?

I'm using Spark 2.4.0.

When executing `val approxQuantiles = flights.stat.approxQuantile(Array("year", "flightEpochSeconds"), Array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 0.25)` I'm not getting it done because there must be such a task that cannot be serializable. I spent some time checking out there the following links, but I'm not able to figure out why this exception.

- [Find quantiles and mean using spark (python and scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark)
- [Statistical and Mathematical functions with DF in Spark from Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html)

### Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$combineByKeyWithClassTag$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.combineByKeyWithClassTag(PairRDDFunctions.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$foldByKey$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.foldByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.multipleApproxQuantiles(StatFunctions.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.approxQuantile(DataFrameStatFunctions.scala:104)
    at airportCaseStudy.CaseStudy$.main(CaseStudy.scala:27)
    at airportCaseStudy.CaseStudy.main(CaseStudy.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.runtime.LazyRef, value: LazyRef thunk)
    - element of array (index: 2)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function0.apply:()Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$foldByKey$2:(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions;[BLscala/runtime/LazyRef;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=()Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$2158/61210602, org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$2158/61210602@165a5979)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 2)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$foldByKey$3:(Lscala/Function0;Lscala/Function2;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=2])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$2159/758750856, org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$2159/758750856@6a6e410c)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    ... 22 more
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: did you try to use scala 2.12? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993313/not-serialazable-exception-while-running-linear-regression-scala-2-12
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743323/dataframe-using-udf-giving-task-not-serializable-exception

Comment: For whatever reason version 2.12.0 threw this exception. Upgraded to 2.12.8 and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add "extends Serializable" to you class or object.

```
class/Object Test extends Serializable{
//type you code
}
```