# Task not serializable Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random-forest

I did this code and I get always this error on the line

```
val randomForestModel = randomForestClassifier.fit(trainingData)
```

the code:

```
val seed = 5043
val Array(trainingData, testData) = labelDf.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3), seed)
trainingData.cache()
testData.cache()

// train Random Forest model with training data set

 val randomForestClassifier = new RandomForestClassifier()
.setImpurity("gini")
.setMaxDepth(3)
.setNumTrees(20)
.setFeatureSubsetStrategy("auto")
.setSeed(seed)

val randomForestModel = randomForestClassifier.fit(trainingData)

println(randomForestModel.toDebugString)
```

The error :

```
ERROR Instrumentation: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Comment: maybe problem in scala version, did you use scala 2.12.8? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531764/spark-dataframe-stat-throwing-task-not-serializable#comment107090455_60531764

Comment: yes I use scala 2.12